# Display the nav arrows outside the swiper-container

Tags: navigation, containers, swiper.js

I'm trying to display the nav arrows outside the swiper-container and not over the slider.
I tried positioning with CSS:

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev{
    right:-20px;
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next{
    background-image:url(assets/img/swiper-left.png);
    left:-20px;
}
```

But the arrows won't display because of the swiper-container CSS overflow: hidden;

So I tried moving the nav arrows outside the swiper-container, now they display but they effect all the Swipers in the page.

My Swiper is configured like this:

```
initialize swiper 
    */
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      // Optional parameters
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution!

By initializing the Swiper with a Jquery .each().
This way, if you move the Swiper arrows outside the Swiper container, they will only control the Swiper they are related to and you can place them wherever you like with CSS. The same thing should also work with pagination.

```
jQuery(function(){ 
    $('.swiper-container').each(function( i ) {
        var mySwiper = new Swiper ($('.swiper-container')[i], {

                // Navigation arrows
                nextButton: $('.swiper-button-prev')[i],
                prevButton: $('.swiper-button-next')[i],

                // Optional parameters
                slidesPerView: 2,

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your solution is not so good. Just try to use other names for swiper-button-prev and swiper-button-next. And create one more inner for slider with position: relative.
example:

```
      <div class="album-slider">
        <div class="album-slider__wrapper  js_album-slider">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="album-slider__item  swiper-slide">
              <img src="img/album2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev  album-slider__button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next  album-slider__button-next"></div>
      </div>
```

and js:

```
var mySwiperAlbum = new Swiper ('.js_album-slider', {
  nextButton: '.album-slider__button-next',
  prevButton: '.album-slider__button-prev',
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  autoplay: 5000,
});
```

css: 
for album-slider set position:relatve;
and for album-slider__wrapper width: 80%;
or if you need slider width: 100%; then set for nav buttons left and right about 
 -30px

Comment: 'your solution is not so good'? Please explain.
As for your solution, it would work if the content is hardcoded but won't work for dynamic content.